# inline block ie7 on h2

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I think im going to kill someone high up in microsoft very very soon:

Please can someone help me get my head around this bug:
http://www.yellostudio.co.uk/tm/selection.html#

I'd like the top h2 to display inline block alongside the help icons on the right.

The issue only exists in ie7 and its doing my sweed in...

Any help would be very very much appreciated

Comment: I already tried the hack which uses:
 zoom:1; *display:inline;

Comment: Put some potatoes out and you can have mash for dinner :P

Comment: :@)  If you dont make light of it you would take a knife to your wrists and end it right there and then...

Comment: Have you tried floating it to the left?

Comment: Chances are the person you want to kill is long retired to some island somewhere and was never very "high up".

Answer (score 0):

I would do float: left on this H2 instead of display-inline and clear: both on form beneath it. Or if there can be different content after H2 then clear:both on everything that will be directly after your icons:

```
#help-icons + * {
  clear: both;
}
```

It works for IE7 also.

Comment: I know float fixes the issue (ish) but it creates others elsewhere because its being content managed.  This would be a last resort i think.  Thanks for helping though.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best practiced way, but why not use a class instead of an h2?

```
.h2class 
{
    /*styles here*/
position:relative;
top:0px;
left:100px; /*use px value that lines it up where you want*/
display:inline-block;/* since IE7 only allows this for naturally inline elements*/
}

<span class="h2class">My Selections</span>
```

Might work...

Comment: Add some more styles, like `position`, `top` and `left`.

Comment: This is unfortunately not a viable solution as im using h2 in many areas of the site.  + its content managed.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts though.

Comment: You loose the margin e.t.c which is exactly why i need inline-block :(

Comment: I meant and inline style for the one h2 tag like: `<h2 style="display:inline-block; margin:5px;..../*whatever styles you want;">My Selections</h2>`

Comment: :@(  The inline style your suggesting isn't any different from what i already have.  Thanks anyway, i've had to hack it completely.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
display: -moz-inline-stack; // for FF2
display: inline-block;
zoom: 1; // HASLAYOUT
*display: inline; // LTE IE7
```

Comment: Kudos for supporting Firefox v2! Not sure that's necessary though; I don't think it has too many users left. (I certainly wouldn't bother)